# UITableViewCell cannot be set transparent entirely with check box

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use below code to try to make tableview cell background clear colour when selected and it works without checkbox but when there is it's not clear colour totally.

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
cell.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIView *selectionView = [UIView new];
selectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setSelectedBackgroundView:selectionView];
```

As you can see from below picture, it's only clear under checkbox but not entire cell. But when there's no checkbox (not editing mode) it's entirely clear. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

If I remove the above code, the result will look like this. The white background will cover entire cell. I don't know why the above code can just set clear background to the area beneath checkbox?

[image]

Comment: Set the alpha of the selectionView.

Answer (score 0):

add this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have find solution, We can edit below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Add below to line
    [self.tblContact setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
    [self.tblContact setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    //tblContact is tableView Outlet
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //ContactTableViewCell is xib file of UITableViewCell
    static NSString *identifier = @"ContactTableViewCell";
    ContactTableViewCell *cell = (ContactTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
    cell.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIView *selectionView = [UIView new];
    selectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [[UITableViewCell appearance] setSelectedBackgroundView:selectionView];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Please tell me about your case Clearly

Comment: I'm guessing it's due to another class which is MessegeCell (UITableView Class) sitting on top of my TableView, so I have to do something there.

Comment: Hello SanitLeee i have edit code, i hope to help for you.

Answer (score 0):

Need to set clear background of cell and cell'contentView.

Answer (score 0):

how about setting the selection style to none instead of blue?

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Comment: if I change it to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone, it can get rid of that white background but also check mark, so that means when I tap nothing visually happens on the table